# Running Bash from java does not work

Tags: java, linux, bash, centos

I have this bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# File to be tagged
inputfile="/dfs/sina/SinaGolestanirad-Project-OneTextEachTime/SinaGolestanirad-Project/Text.txt"
#inputfile="test/SampleInputs/longParagraph.txt"
# Tagged file to be created
#outputfile="test/SampleOutputs/NERTest.conll.tagged.txt"
outputfile="/dfs/sina/SinaGolestanirad-Project-OneTextEachTime/SinaGolestanirad-Project/1.Generate-Basic-Questions/Tagged-Named-Entites-Text.txt"
# Config file
#configfile="config/conll.config"
configfile="config/ontonotes.config"
# Classpath
cpath="target/classes:target/dependency/*"
CMD="java -classpath  ${cpath} -Xmx8g edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.LbjNer.LbjTagger.NerTagger -annotate ${inputfile} ${outputfile} ${configfile}"
echo "$0: running command '$CMD'..."
$CMD
```

When I run either java codes below they do not give any errors but they just show the bash file in my Eclipse Console, in other words they do not run the bash !! and the value for process.exitValue() is 1, by the way, my OS is `CentOS`, linux.

Firs JAVA code :

```
try {
     Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
     process.waitFor();
     System.out.println(process.exitValue());
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Second JAVA code :

```
    String command = "/dfs/sina/SinaGolestanirad-Project-OneTextEachTime/"
            + "SinaGolestanirad-Project/1.Generate-Basic-Questions/1.IllinoisNerExtended-DO-NOT-OPEN-BY-ECLIPSE/plaintextannotate-linux.sh";
     StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/bash",command};
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println(output.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I also checked the bash file permission and it is executable as a program.

How can I run the bash file? The bash should run another program written in java.

Comment: Check the exit code. Read from stderr. There are a lot of things that could be happening.

Comment: #LeBarton what is the exit code?

Comment: p.exitValue()  . All programs return an integer to the OS. If a program returns 0, it finished normally. If it is not 0, it encountered an error.

Comment: #LeBarton it's 1 , what should I do?

Comment: can anybody help? I am still stuck here !!

Answer (score 0):

-- LeBarton what is the exit code?

Check the output of p.exitValue()

Comment: it's 1, what does it mean? and what should I do?

Comment: 1. Check the script permission (if the user running Java process has execute permission)

Comment: #Chartar What is the script permission?

Comment: I would suggest you first run the script directly to make sure you can run it. if you can run it successfully, next step is to run suing Java program with the help of code suggested by LeBarton.

Comment: I run the bash in terminal and it works good, but I can not run it by java code

Answer (score 0):

```
p.waitFor()

InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());

While (inputStreamReader.ready()) { System.out.println(inputStreamReader.read(); }
```

This will show you the error output. Add this to the bottom below the try.. catch.

You will see the output that you would see on the command line. It will help you narrow down the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link which may help, if your bash read some environmental variables.

[$PATH variable isn't inherited through getRuntime().exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984138/path-variable-isnt-inherited-through-getruntime-exec)