# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "set": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, command-line, operating-system

I am trying to run set command from eclipse, but i am getting the below exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "set": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
```

Here is my piece of code:

```
String command = "set Path=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11566302/4065876

Answer (score 10):

The program fails because `set` is not an executable but a command inside the command processor `cmd.exe`.

To invoke it use

```
String command = "cmd.exe /c set path=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/bin";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

But be aware of the pitfalls of setting environment variables, see [How to set an environment variable in Java using exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607249/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-in-java-using-exec) as mentionend in the comments by @Berger

Comment: Have doubt that, ping command is working without adding 'cmd' before it.then why only set has this problem, can u please elaborate the reason why should i use 'cmd'?

Comment: Windows has a `ping.exe` and therefore you can start it using `Runtime.exec` but there is no `set.exe` (and no `echo.exe`, `dir.exe` ...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is really amazing..