# Getting java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cf": error=2, No such file or directory error when I execute cf commands using java

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, microservices, cloud-foundry

Getting java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cf": error=2, No such file or directory error  when I execute cf commands using java code Runtime.getRuntime().exec(testCommand); in MAC.

Same commands are working fine when I execute from the CLI.

Is there any environment variables need to set for cf?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a command from the command line, the shell knows where to find the executable because it has access to the PATH environment variable, which contains a list of directories where executable files are located. However, when running a command from a Java program using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, the system might not have access to the same PATH environment variable.

To resolve this issue, you can either provide the full path to the "cf" executable in your Java code, or you can modify the PATH environment variable for the Java process.

Regarding modifying the PATH for the Java process, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984138/path-variable-isnt-inherited-through-getruntime-exec) a previous SO question.